# Android: is it posible set webView's cache duration?

Tags: android, caching, webview

I would like to know if is possible to set the expiry duration of a file in cache memory when it has been load in a webView.

In my case, I am loading always the same URL image into a webView. In spite of to be the same URL, the image will be able to change in anytime.

I wouldn't like disable the cache memory, but I am wondering if is possible to set a determinate expiry duration to this file, like 5, 10... or 30 minutes for example.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To force the browser to fetch a new image every time, add a unique query parameter. For example:

http://example.com/images/file.png?q=1

http://example.com/images/file.png?q=2

And so on. Normally, a timestamp value can be used to generate a unique value.